# How to change the name of upload button to Please wait..?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to change the value of the upload button when the file is busy uploading

In this case if the value of my upload button is `value="Upload"` when the button is clicked text must change to **Uploading Please wait..**

```js
function displayLoading() { 
    if (document.getElementById('upload-progress')) { 
        document.getElementById('upload-progress').style.display='block'; 
    } 
}
```

```html
<form action="myphpscript.php" onSubmit="displayLoading();"> 
    <input type="file" name="uploadfile"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"> 
    <p  id="upload-progress" style="display:none">Uploading Please wait..</p> 
</form>
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem with changing the name of button? You don't know how to reference it, or...?

Comment: I got it fixed thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the submit Button an ID, for example `submitButton`.

Then just add:

```
document.getElementById('submitButton').value = "Please Wait";
```

to your `displayLoading()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the button while it's uploading and re-enable when it's complete. Otherwise the user can keep pressing the button causing another call to your PHP.